# Freemarker doesn't work in StrutsSpringTestCase

Tags: struts2, freemarker

Basically, I'm trying to run a simple unit test but cannot make it work when I use freemarker as the result type. Other types like jsp or redirectAction worked fine. What am I missing?

**ForwardActionTest.java:**

```
public class ForwardActionTest extends StrutsSpringTestCase {
    ....
    public void testExecuteAction() throws Exception {
        String output = executeAction("/home.do"); <--- Exception points here
        ...
    }
}
```

**struts.xml**

```
<action name="home" class="forwardAction">
    <result type="freemarker">templates/home.ftl</result>
</action>
```

**templates/home.ftl**

```
Hello! You are home!
```

**Stacktrace:**

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Error code [500], Error: [Template /templates/home.ftl not found.]
at org.apache.struts2.StrutsTestCase.executeAction(StrutsTestCase.java:120)
at com.telus.ccs.survey.web.action.ForwardActionTest.testExecuteAction(ForwardActionTest.java:22)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at junit.framework.TestCase.runTest(TestCase.java:176)
at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:141)
at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:122)
at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:142)
at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:125)
at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:129)
at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:255)
at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:250)
at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.run(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:84)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```